# Unable to use jQuery Validation engine with bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validation-engine

I'm trying to use jQuery Validation Engine to validate input fields. I'm using it on a page, which requires bootstrap for it's design.

For some reason,  the validation engine doesn't work, and no errors are being thrown.

I've gone through some questions here on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to be helping.
(All my links/relations are correct).

Here's my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    </script>
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#fm").validationEngine();
        });

    
        </script>
        

            <div class="row-fluid sortable">
                <div class="box span12">
                    <div class="box-header well" data-original-title>
                        <h2><i class="icon-picture"></i>Change Password</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <form action="#" id="fm">
                        <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="disabledInput">Email</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <input class="input-xlarge disabled" id="disabledInput" type="text" value="<?php echo $ret['email']; ?>" disabled="">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" name="test" id="test" class="validate[required] text-input">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/span-->
            
            </div><!--/row-->
```

Comment: What make you thing it's a conflict with bootstrap? Try to comment-out `bootstrap.js` file and see if your form validates?

Comment: @MuhammadReda

If I do not use bootstrap, everything seems to be working fine.
Commenting out bootstrap.js didn't help as well.

Comment: Works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/84PVv/1/)

Comment: @NetStack; can you paste a link for your page?